# ¿Cómo puedo copiar un archivo con shutil y crear una excepción si no existe?

Tags: python

Trato de copiar un archivo de una carpeta a otra, pero al momento de copiar ciertos archivos que no existen, el programa simplemente se me detiene sin seguir iterando:

```
from shutil import copytree, Error
import shutil
import os

def main():

    try:
        shutil.copy2(r"C:/Users/youna/3D Objects/A/numeroA.png", r"C:/Users/youna/Downloads/IO/A/numeroA.png")

        
        #Supongamos que este archivo no existe
        shutil.copy2(r"C:/Users/youna/3D Objects/A/numeroB.png", r"C:/Users/youna/Downloads/IO/A/numeroB.png")

        shutil.copy2(r"C:/Users/youna/3D Objects/A/numeroC.png", r"C:/Users/youna/Downloads/IO/A/numeroC.png")


    except (FileNotFoundError, shutil.Error) as error:
       print(error)
       pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Mi pregunta es: ¿cómo puedo seguir iterando en caso de que el archivo que no existe me arroje excepción?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando estás iterando sobre algún contenedor, el patrón usual para capturar las excepciones y seguir procesando el siguiente elemento es:

```
for elemento in lista:
    try:
       # Ejecutar acción con potencial de excepción.
    except alguna_excepción as error:
       # Ejecutar acción recuperativa/informativa
```

Aplicado al caso en cuestión, debemos primero reestructurar el código para hacerlo iterativo, poniendo los archivos a copiar en una lista de tuplas:

```
archivos = [("origen.txt", "destino.txt"),
            ("no.txt", "si.txt")
            ]
```

Y luego iteramos sobre la lista para copiar uno a uno:

```
for origen, destino in archivos:
    try:
        print(f"Copiand {origen} a {destino}")
        shutil.copy2(origen, destino)
    except (FileNotFoundError, shutil.Error) as error:
        print(error)
```

No hay acción correctiva que tomar, excepto informar del error.

#### Demo

```
import shutil

def main(a_copiar):
    for origen, destino in a_copiar:
        try:
            print(f"Copiando {origen} a {destino}")
            shutil.copy2(origen, destino)
        except (FileNotFoundError, shutil.Error) as error:
            print(error)

archivos = [("origen.txt", "destino.txt"),
            ("no.txt", "si.txt")
            ]

main(archivos)
```

produce:

```
Copiando origen.txt a destino.txt
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'origen.txt'
Copiando no.txt a si.txt
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'no.txt'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Funciona, muchas gracias!